# Is there a way to configure images so that quality is consistent (not stretch) on HTML

Tags: html, css, node.js, bootstrap-5

This is my inside a card-group div. I am using bootstrap pre-built components. Products is an array of JSON objects of products for a shopping store.

```
<div class="card-group">
        <% products.forEach((product) => { %>
        <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px">
          <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img
                src="/uploads/<%= product.image %>"
                class="img-fluid rounded-start"
                style="height: 12rem; width: 100%"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><%= product.name %></h5>
                <p class="card-text"><%= product.description %></p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                  <small class="text-body-secondary">View More</small></a
                >
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% }) %>
      </div>
```

The problem is that if the displayed images are of various sizes, are there any technqiues/tricks to preserve quality (without stretching the image) for all images.

I have tried playing around with the height and width property such as:

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

But then the images becomes unaligned as shown[Misaligned images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFpaQ.png):

Another possibility I could do is to center the images in the dead center so as to prodivde some consistency, but I also do not know how do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is set a fixed with, auto height and a background on the container which would be full height of the cell/content needed. If you would center the image inside that container it would look consistent.

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin:auto;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 800px;
  width:400px;
}
```